# 2 forms in a button WINFORM

Tags: c#, winforms, overlapping

is it possible that when I click a button 2 forms will show but I should fulfill a request in form 2 in order to go to form 1 for example

form 3 button show ==> 2 forms appear ==> 1st form 1, 2nd form 2 ==> i should press ok in form 2 in order to go to form 1 ==> I cannot switch into form 1 unless I click the button ok in form 2.

it's like similar when you are installing you should click next2x finish in order to go to the background form which is the installing process. similar concept like that THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spit-balling here but you could do something like this:

```
// untested...
firstForm.Show();
if (secondForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Ok)
{
    firstForm.Close();
}
```

Comment: You may want to call it like "secondForm.ShowDialog(firstForm)" to assert the firstForm as the parent of the 2nd form, to make sure it is locked out until the dialog is closed.